# some times my xmpp server not connecting?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmppframework

Hi I am working with the Xmpp framework working fine.Now I am facing one issue some times my xmpp server not respond.`xmppStreamDidDisconnect` This method is calling every time.and below is error log

`Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out}`

If any body knows what exactly that one is.Please help me Thank you.

Comment: plz provide code, where you tried to connect with xmpp server

Comment: Thanks for the replay before it is working fine but now it getting above error

Comment: are you using any google framework like analytics etc... because of this https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/577

Comment: no I'm not using.any way some times it is coming i mean not connected to server.actualy why above error gets called .